# Extra item in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an extra radio button with some choices inside an existing rails form (I use simple_form gem). The problem is that I do not want this to point in any field in my model. I want it to be an **extra** field that I would like to pass.

All examples that I found introduces a hidden tag. But I do not want it to be hidden I want a radio button set.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using radio_button_tag inside the modal form, I have used it in the past. An example would be:

```
radio_button_tag 'send_me_updates', 'radio', false
```

When you submit the form, I think you will be able to access the radio button value with `params[:send_me_updates]`. Should work, please try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks mate. I found that you can also do that with html as well. `<input type="radio" name="friend" value="male" /> Sex?<br />` I was just thinking that the value would have been in the params[] sent by the form. I was wrong. It is in a new parameter:) Thanks a lot again:)

Comment: It is never advisable to mix pure HTML and erbs. Thanks for accepting my answer.